# Email template - Order items layout - not appearing

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I'm setting up a website running on Magento 2.3.4

I've run into an issue with sending emails to buyers. The email template I created through the admin interface is supposed to show the items bought. However it isn't rendering the section with the layout directive.

This is the line I'm talking about:

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

If i send an email using the default template meant for a new order, then the email contains the itemized list

I'm not quite sure why, but the new strict mode introduced in 2.3.4 seems to have broken how the layout directive works.

Does anyone know how to render the itemized list from the order in the email?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Temp solution is:

set in db table: email_template column  is_legacy = 1 for this new order email template.

Comment: This is not working in magento 2.4.1 enterprise edition

Comment: working fine, thank you!

Comment: what means legacy template

Answer (score 5):

put this line instead of the one you have:
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order_id=$order_id area="frontend"}}

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

the solution of Domagoj Potkoč is ok but temp.

This module fix the bug - it will automated previous solution:
[FixAdminEmailTemplate](https://github.com/htcmage/m2-fix-admin-email-template)

Answer (score 0):

> create plugin to resolve this

> di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Email\Model\Template">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="FixAdminEmailTemplate_Plugin_Magento_Email_Model_Template" sortOrder="10" type="Test\Module\Plugin\EmailTemplate"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> EmailTemplate.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Test\Module\Plugin;

class EmailTemplate 
{
    public function beforeBeforeSave(\Magento\Email\Model\Template $subject)
    {
        $subject->setData('is_legacy', 1);
        return [];
    }
}
```